# How I store business hours in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website involving local restaurants, and one thing I need to do is store Restaurant Operating Hours in mysql.

Data comes from HTML to PHP is look like this.

```
// Eg: from Monday to Saturday 8am to 10pm
$_POST['from'], $_POST['to'], $_POST['opening_time'], $_POST['closing_time']
```

My `sql` table structure is something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE business_hours (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  restaurant_id integer NOT NULL,
  day integer NOT NULL,
  open_time time,
  close_time time
)
```

My question is I am getting two days from users like above with its opening and closing time. So Now I need to insert into `business_hours` table with all the records between this two days.

Eg: `Monday`, `Friday` (if the opening and closing period of a week)

Then I need to store these operating hours in my table like this

```
Monday,9am,11pm
Tuesday,9am,11pm
Wednesday,9am,11pm
Thursday,9am,11pm
Friday,9am,11pm
```

Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: move day,open_time, and close_time to a separate table called hours_of_operation (or whatever). add another column restaurant_id to the 2nd table which will match the values in your first table.  Then you can have multiple entries in the 2nd table for each restaurant and restaurant_id will be the link (relation) between the two.  Search for "relational database one to many" for more info about the concept

Comment: @CrayonViolent, can you tell me why I need to have two table for this and why its cannot have multiple entries which belong to one restaurant in my `business_hours` table?

Comment: if the data is like this how you come to know what the year and what is month and what is day for all records?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, Actually its not necessary to know whats the month and year. Because users can update there availability on weekly basis.

Comment: @TNK sure, you can keep as-is and have multiple entries with same `restaurant_id` values.  But in general it's better practice to separate all the "single entry" stuff from the "multiple entry" stuff.  It basically boils down to efficiency.

Comment: You can manipulate From (Monday/Wednesday) and To (Thrusday/Friday) values in PHP page and insert the required records.

Comment: Still I am no sense, how to implement this...

Comment: A Lookup table would help say Id, Day as fields (1, Monday), (2, Tuesday), (3, Wednesday)...as values Select day between from and to you will get the record and try inserting those records

Answer (score 2):

After much research, trial and error this is what finally worked for me. The data is all based on the entries of a restaurant for dynamic structured markup.

The SQL for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_businesshrs (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tbl_index_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`DoW` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('Open','Closed') NOT NULL COMMENT '0 is Cosed',
`start_time` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`end_time` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The tbl_index_id is the id of the restaurant in the restaurant table and it is an INDEX and DoW is day of the week.

I also included AJAX functions to update the business hours table when the hours are changed. Then on the restaurant setting php page I included a record source query for every day of the week that updates the select fields with the values stored in the database.

The query:

```
<?php 
$colname_rs_mondayshrs = "-1"; 
if (isset($_GET['restaurantid'])) { 
  $colname_rs_mondayshrs = $_GET['restaurantid']; 
} 
mysqli_select_db( $restaurant, $database_restaurant); 
$query_rs_mondayshrs = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_businesshrs WHERE tbl_index_id = %s 
AND DoW='Monday'", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_mondayshrs, "int")); 
$rs_mondayshrs = mysqli_query( $restaurant, $query_rs_mondayshrs) or 
die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])); 
$row_rs_mondayshrs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_mondayshrs); 
$totalRows_rs_mondayshrs = mysqli_num_rows($rs_mondayshrs);    

?>
```

And so on for every day of the week. Then the magnificent [PHP stcrcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function compares the open and closed entries from the database and fills the select options with the relevant entry:

```
<select id="mondaystatus" onChange="update_mondaystatus()">
                      <option selected value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", 
$row_rs_mondayshrs['status']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Open or Closed? 
</option>
                      <option value="Open" <?php if (!(strcmp("Open", 
$row_rs_mondayshrs['status']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Open</option>
                      <option value="Closed" <?php if (!(strcmp("Closed", 
$row_rs_mondayshrs['status']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Closed</option>
                    </select>
```

The result:

[image]

and the result in the db:

[image]

I can add the AJAX function if anyone is interested or if it could help save someone some valuable time.

Comment: You should work on your naming. `tbl_index_id` is very strange name for a column ;) It does not say at all that this is a key of the restaurant. Cheers

Comment: Thank you @DamianDziaduch. Appreciate it :-)

Comment: How to update a specific hour? should it be done by searching which day record has changed and update the column value or delete all rows and insert new?

Comment: @ Biswas Khayargoli no you do not need to delete all rows. It is an ajax function. If you change the hour for any row it will update the db with that value only.

Comment: @nawissor what if I wanted to save all day's timing at once, instead of ajax call on each time.

Comment: @IwanRoss Is there any way of your restaurants have 2 opened spots at the same day? (eg. friday from 11am-2pm and 5pm-9pm)

Comment: @MikeAlvim I can not think of a way to achieve what it is you want to achieve.